# Getting 404 not found while creating new json file by Angular $resource

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I created a service using ngResource to save the data of form in json format. But after submitting form I got 404 error for 999.json file.

**ServiceJS**

```
"use strict";
eventsApp.factory("eventData", function ($resource, $q) {
    var resource = $resource("data/:id.json", {
        id: "@id"
    });
    return {
        getEvent: function () {
            var deffered = $q.defer();
            resource.get({
                    id: "event"
                },
                function (event) {
                    deffered.resolve(event);
                },
                function (status) {
                    deffered.reject(status);
                });
            return deffered.promise;
        },
        save: function (event) {
            var deffered = $q.defer();
            event.id = 999;
            resource.save(event,
                function (data, status, header, config) {
                    deffered.resolve(data);
                },
                function (data, status, header, config) {
                    deffered.reject(data);
                }
            );
            return deffered.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

**ControllerJS**

```
eventsApp.controller('editEventCtrl', function ($scope, eventData) {
    // Save Event
    $scope.saveEvent = function (event, newEventForm) {
        if (newEventForm.$valid) {
            //alert("Event '" + event.ename + "' Saved Successfully !");
            eventData.save(event)
                .then(
                    function (response) {
                        console.log('Success ' + JSON.stringify(response));
                    },
                    function (response) {
                        console.log('Failure ' + JSON.stringify(response));
                    }
            )
        }
    };
});
```

Please help me.

Comment: "But after submitting form I got 404 error for 999.json file" what do you mean? are you trying to use ngResource to create a file?

Comment: Last I checked, `404` meant `file not found`. Are you submitting to the wrong path. Did you run Firebug or Developer Mode to see what URL the browser is submitting to? Did you check the logs from the server? Post them all here...

Comment: @rahpuser yes I am creating new file with ngResource save function.

Comment: btw, resource.get and resource.save have an inner promise, is consider an antipattern to create a deferred to encapsulate promises.. see https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern... ngResource makes a request to the server, if you are getting 404 error, means that the url is not the correct, whats the server url need? whats the console error ?

Comment: this is error i m getting in console. `POST http://localhost:8000/app/data/999.json 404 (Not Found) angular.js:8609
Failure {"data":"Not found\n","status":404,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"data":{"ename":"Test","date":"11/11/1111","time":"dsf","address":"sadf","city":"asdf","provience":"fdsafa","id":999},"url":"data/999.json","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"Not Found"}`

Comment: @RakeshKumar You can not create files with ngResource. I imagine you are using and endpoint which is the one that is going to create the file in the server right? if that's the case, you server URL is not found. Are you sure that's the correct URL ?